# In Angular 4, how do you convert a FormGroup into a URL with query parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, query-string

In my Angular app, I have a multifield Reactive Form which users can use to search our internal database.

When the user clicks "Search" I want to route to a `SearchResultsComponent` to display the results. I also want the route in the browser to contain query parameters that represent the form input, so the user can copy it somewhere and re-use it easily. Essentially, as I imagine it, visiting `https://carsuniverse.com/?make=Honda&model=Civic&year=2009` should activate the `SearchResultsComponent` which in turn calls a service that performs the search, returns it to the component and displays it on the page

What is the best (or a good way at least) to do this in Angular?

Comment: Well, how do you navigate to another route? Using Router.navigate(), right? How do you pass query parameters to [that method](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate)? Using the [NavigationExtras.queryParams](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#queryParams). What's the [type of this field](https://angular.io/api/router/Params)? It's an object containing keys and values. Isn't that what the value of a FormGroup is? an object with the control names as keys and their values as value?

Comment: @JBNizet but there may be nested objects inside. It's unclear how it treats those. I guess I have to try it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
const formValue = this.form.value; // this.form should be a FormGroup

for (const key in formValue) {
    params.append(key, formValue[key]);
}
```

We grab the object that is the form value, and for each key we append the value to a `URLSearchParams` object, which can then be passed to the `Http` library when making requests.

You may want to think about the implications of this if the form is deeply nested.

**UPDATE**

If you want deeply nested forms to be represented in the query params, you'll have to modify the `for` loop slightly. But here is an example of how your query might look for deeply nested objects:

```
{
    name: 'John',
    favorites: {
        food: 'Pizza',
        candy: 'Jolly Ranchers'
    }
}
```

The object above could be represented like this:

```
?name=John&favorites[food]=Pizza&favorites[candy]=Jolly+Ranc‌​hers
```

Comment: Right so that's what I'm worried about.  If I make a change to my form structure now I'll have to modify this function?  I could see that leading to a lot of messiness

Comment: No, you won't have to. This function loops through all the keys in your form, so it doesn't matter what's in there or if you modify it, the function will always work. What I'm referring to is if you have a form group within a form group, thus giving you an object with other objects in it as a value. That's when this would break, because it only allows a flat object as it is.

Comment: Yes that's actually what I meant

Comment: But all you have to do is modify the `for` loop to account for a deeply nested object. That functionality will depend on how you want your final query params to be structured for arrays and so on. I'll leave that as an exercise for you :) but my answer should suffice for your question.

Comment: If you ever have problems achieving this, let me know and I'll cook something up for you. Updated answer to give an example of how it might look.